# LibGDX: Eclipse Import Gradle 'CreateProcess error = 5'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, project

While importing a LibGDX Gradle project in Eclipse I get the following error once the "Build Model" button is pressed:

IMAGE OF SCREEN FOR BETTER REFERENCE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqOyj.png

Title Bar: "Error in runnable 'Creating Gradle model'"
Content of error box: "CreateProcess error = 5, Access is denied"

Any help would be appreciated, I could not find anything on this error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago, but I might as well still post the answer in case someone encounters this error - simply make sure you have the latest Java version/JDK/SDK on your system and Eclipse is using it!